# How to initialize a new field of an inner class with constructor?

Tags: java, initialization, inner-classes

If I have this class and I want to initialize a new field of type `Element`,
how I can do that

```
public class MyLinkedList{

   protected Element head, tail;

   public final class Element{
      Object data;
      int priority; 
      Element next;

      Element(Object obj, int priorit, Element element){
       data = obj;
       priority = priorit;
       next = element;
      }
   }
}
```

when I try to do this it gave me an error

```
public class PriorityTest{
    public static void main(String[]args){  
        MyLinkedList.Element e1 = new MyLinkedList.Element("any", 4, null); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the inner class is not static, an instance of the inner class cannot exist on it's own. If this is what you want, declare the inner class static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
MyLinkedList.Element e1 = new MyLinkedList().new Element("any", 4, null);
```

your inner class is not `static` so you need to create an object of outer class first.

Comment: Or, if the Element class doesn't need to refer to the list's `head` and `tail` then make it a static class instead of an inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner calss static

```
public class MyLinkedList{

   protected Element head, tail;

   public static final class Element{
      Object data;
      int priority;
      Element next;

      Element(Object obj, int priorit, Element element){
       data = obj;
       priority = priorit;
       next = element;
      }
   }

  public static void main(String[]args){
      MyLinkedList.Element e1 = new MyLinkedList.Element("any", 4, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot
but when I tried to compile it it shows me this error:
error: an enclosing instance that contains MyLinkedList.Element is required
        MyLinkedList.Element e1 = new MyLinkedList.Element(new String("any"), 4, null);